# Shopify how can I add theme settings section?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I know that to add sections or blocks, I just create a structure like this inside my template:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "icons",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "label": "your headline for the section"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

But how do I get my sections that I added in settings_schema.json and add to a specific template equal to the image?

[image]

Comment: Theme settings act as global into Shopify and you can use theme anywhere, in any layout, section or snippets, assets files. you not need to add them like sections anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the @Onkar reply! But what I really wanted is to understand how I can make the "Theme settings" tab appear inside an equal section in the image.

Comment: You can the new theme settings sub child along with section appear due to Shopify logic and I think it shows the that settings that are used on this page or something else. you need to consult with Shopify support for it

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT) Ok I'm re-writing this now that I know what you're trying to do, based on your comment.

To get your settings to appear in the Theme Settings section of the Customizer you will need to edit `settings_schema.json`. You will need to understand how JSON works as well.

When you open `settings_schema.json` it will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "theme_info",
    "theme_name": "Some Theme Name",
    "theme_author": "Author Name",
    "theme_version": "1.5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Custom Feature",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "enable_feature",
        "label": "Enable Feature",
        "default": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Popup Message",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "paragraph",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, dicta quae fugiat beatae ullam sit iure at."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You will need to add your section into the file. It would probably be easiest to add it to the end. All of the sections are wrapped in square brackets `[ ]` (which makes it an array) and you need to find the last section between the outer most square brackets. In my example code above, it would be the Popup Message section. That section is wrapped in curly brackets `{ }` (which makes it an object). Go to the closing curly bracket and put a comma just after it and then press enter. On the new line, paste in your schema code.

It would look like this with your section added:

```
[
  {
    "name": "theme_info",
    "theme_name": "Some Theme Name",
    "theme_author": "Author Name",
    "theme_version": "1.5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Custom Feature",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "enable_feature",
        "label": "Enable Feature",
        "default": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Popup Message",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "paragraph",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, dicta quae fugiat beatae ullam sit iure at."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "icons",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "your headline for the section"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Save the file and refresh the customizer.  You should see your new section at the bottom of Theme Settings.

Comment: What I want is to make it appear in the "Theme Settings" tab within a section

Comment: @AksJacoves ok I re-wrote the answer. Please check and let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and I am sorry for the delay. I forgot to give you a detail. What I wanted was for this "theme settings" section to be displayed on a specific page. For example, "products page"....

Comment: As you put it, this section will be displayed globally on the left side, while sections of a specific page are displayed on the right side. But it was my mistake not to explain this detail. No need to change, thanks for the answer!

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the upvote. When you add a section to Theme Settings it will always be global. That's the purpose of Theme Settings. To make it appear in a specific template, then the schema needs to be added to the section that is associated with the template. Hope that helps. Shopify has pretty good documentation with examples. You might find some more answers there.

Comment: I found out how to do this and I'll leave it here in the comment if anyone finds this question.

Comment: Just add an object in settings_schema.json and in the page template, for example product-template.liquid for product in some themes, just call the object created in settings_schema.json by making settings['id_object'] anywhere in the template and automatically it goes to the theme settings tab.